Broken dpkg prevents installing python3 on Ubuntu 24.04
I've recently updated WLS2-Win11 to Ubuntu 24.04 on my Intel-CPU computer. After removing Python 3.8, I tried installing Python 3.12.
Command sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade leads to the following error:
...                                                                                                                                                         The following upgrades have been deferred due to phasing:
  libopeniscsiusr needrestart open-iscsi
The following packages have been kept back:
  bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs binutils binutils-common
  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu btrfs-progs build-essential chafa coreutils cpp
  cpp-11 cpp-9 cron cryptsetup-initramfs curl dbus dbus-user-session dbus-x11
  dirmngr dmeventd e2fsprogs file fonts-dejavu-core fonts-urw-base35 fuse
  fwupd g++ g++-11 gcc gcc-11 gcc-11-base gcc-9 gcc-9-base ghostscript git
  git-man gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client
  gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gpgv gsfonts imagemagick-6.q16 initramfs-tools
  initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core iproute2 jp2a
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libargon2-1 libasan5 libasan6 libbinutils
  libcairo2 libctf0 libdbus-1-3 libfido2-1 libfile-fcntllock-perl libfreetype6
  libfwupd2 libgcc-11-dev libgcc-9-dev libgd3 libgl1-amber-dri libgl1-mesa-dri
  libglapi-mesa libglx-mesa0 libgudev-1.0-0 libheif1 libintl-perl
  libintl-xs-perl libjxr-tools liblocale-gettext-perl liblvm2cmd2.03                                                                                          libmagic-mgc libmm-glib0 libncurses6 libncursesw6 libnsl2 libnss-nisplus
  libnss-systemd libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-systemd libplymouth5
  libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libproc-processtable-perl
  libpulse0 libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libsemanage-common libserf-1-1
  libsndfile1 libstdc++-11-dev libsvn1 libsystemd0 libterm-readkey-perl
  libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libtinfo6 libtsan0 libudev1
  libvolume-key1 libwebp7 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux3 libxaw7 libxml2 lsof lvm2
  mesa-vulkan-drivers modemmanager multipath-tools ncurses-base ncurses-bin                                                                                   ncurses-term netpbm ntfs-3g open-vm-tools parted passwd perl perl-base
  pkexec plymouth plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text policykit-1 polkitd procps
  pulseaudio-utils sg3-utils subversion systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd
  tcpdump telnet thin-provisioning-tools tmux udev udisks2 w3m w3m-img wget
  x11-utils zerofree
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 156 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Setting up python3 (3.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.12...
running python post-rtupdate hooks for python3.12...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.postinst: 47: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed

At this time, no python was installed on my machine. I tried sudo apt-get install python3 --reinstall, and it returned
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 156 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for python3:amd64

Command whereis python3 returned python3: /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3 /usr/share/python3. Commands sudo dpkg --configure -a, sudo apt autoremove   and sudo apt-get install -f returned simmilar error as sudo apt-get upgrade shown above.
Command sudo apt remvoe python3 returned:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libpython3-stdlib
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python3
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 156 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 84.0 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.12-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.12' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 35623 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python3 (3.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.prerm: 5: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--remove):
 installed python3 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.postinst: 47: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Q1: how can I fix it w/o reinstalling ubuntu?
Q2: If it's necessary to reintall ubuntu? How can I retain data given this WSL2 environment?
Update 1
Results of sudo apt list ...
python3-minimal/noble,now 3.12.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3.12-minimal/noble,now 3.12.3-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

The result of file $(which apt)
/usr/bin/apt: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=8c9aa55bd74c35500c2014ff0674dd5eb481b82b, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

And python3[.12] returns command not found
Update 2
Command sudo apt install --reinstall python3-minimal python3.12-minimal  returns
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.12-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.12' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 35623 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3.12-minimal_3.12.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.12-minimal (3.12.3-1) over (3.12.3-1) ...
Setting up python3.12-minimal (3.12.3-1) ...
# Empty sitecustomize.py to avoid a dangling symlink
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3.12'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 0
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 0
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = '/usr/lib/python3.12'
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3.12'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3.12'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python312.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.12',
    '/usr/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fe6d634e080 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
dpkg: error processing package python3.12-minimal (--configure):
 installed python3.12-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.12-minimal
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

'Solution'
I tried everything I could find to fix it, but none of them work. Finally I reinstalled the entire wls-ubuntu.

Please note:  important functions in Ubuntu consist of python code, at least parts of apt itself is an example, so; remove python and you're "stranded". I'd say the easy way to recover is to reinstall Ubuntu.

It might be salvageable. Please edit your question to include the complete output of sudo apt list python3-minimal and of  sudo apt list python3.12-minimal. The underlying problem shown in your output is that some files from those two files seem to be missing and merely need to be reinstalled. Did you happen to uninstall either of those packages? Are you have disk problems?

Hmm... file $(which apt) => 'elf binary', now my 24.04 says $ python --version => Python 3.12.3 is WSL not fully the same, maybe.

@user535733 The disk runs fine. I did remove several python3.8 and python3.12 directories, but cannot remember which is which.

Perhaps you (unwisely) removed files placed by dpkg. Never do that. It breaks your system in exactly this kind of way. Try sudo apt install --reinstall python3-minimal python3.12-minimal to restore the files. If it works, it will restore the missing pycompile, the key problem shown in your output.

@user535733 It does not work. It seems broken dpkg loses some info of python3 while some flags set it to be installed? I tried to fix dpkg in the OP, but failed.

If dpkg does not work, your easiest fix would be to backup and reinstall WSL. Please never mess with system python in Ubuntu. If you need a different python version, use anaconda/virtual environments instead.

This question is similar to: apt and dpkg fail because of very broken python. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You have missing critical files.
Those files, on Ubuntu 24.04, are provided by the packages python3.12-minimal and python3-minimal
To salvage your system, you must reinstall those packages. Usually you can use apt or dpkg to do that reinstallation.
If you cannot reinstall those packages, then your system is not salvageable. Preserve your data, and then reinstall Ubuntu.

As it was said python3-minimal and python3.12-minimal caused the issue.
In my case, the sosreport package was broken too.
apt install --reinstall python3-minimal python3.12-minimal -y
apt install --reinstall sosreport -y

The error:
:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
.....
Get:22 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports/multiverse amd64 Components [212 B]
Fetched 1,381 kB in 2s (665 kB/s)
Segmentation fault
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code

